# Power BI combine results from two SQL-Server tables

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

While using Power BI for a few months now, we (the user group) encountered an issue that is not really clear to us.

We use Power-BI with a remote SQL-Server data source, we access the data source through direct query.

Let's pretend we have 2 Tables as below-

```
Table name: Issue
Column: 
    ResolutionTime(Date/Time) 
    IssueID(Unique Numbers)
```

```
Table Name: WorkItem
Column: 
    start (Date/Time)
    end (Date/Time)
    IssueID (Unique Numbers, Foreign Key to "Issue" table)
```

Table WorkItem also contain a calculated column "WorkTime" which uses this DAX-expression as below-

```
WorkTime = WorkItem[end] - WorkItem[start]
```

The two tables are configured through Power-Bi having a two-way 1:n relationship that can be queried to collect all "WorkItem"(s) assigned to an "Issue" entry, using the "IssueID" as correlation column.

To be able to compute the aggregated "work-time" for each "WorkItem", we use a new/calculated table with the following DAX expression to aggregate the total amount of time invested for a single "Issue":

```
SumWork =
SUMMARIZE(
  WorkItem, WorkItem[IssueID], "All work per item", SUM(WorkItem[WorkTime])
)
```

The above table computes the total invested work-time for a particular issue, grouping/summarizing results based on the "IssueID" foreign key. This new calculated table is also configured to have a relationship with the "Issue" table, this time a "1:1" relationship, using the IssueID as correlation column.

Now to compute the time that the issue was worked on + the time for Resolution should be summarized in a calculated column inside "Issue", but this does not work:

```
ResolutionAndWorkTime = Issue[ResolutionTime] + SumWork["All work per item"]
```

But the above DAX expression fails to compile, as it always reports that it returns "more than one result", thus not being a singular result. But that is suprising, as the two table ("Issue" and "SumWork" are related to each other with a "1:1" relationship).

Tables:

```
Issues
IssueID     ResolutionTime     ResolutionAndWorkTime
1           03:20:20            ???
2           01:20:20            ???
3           00:20:20            ???

WorkItem
IssueID     start                  end                   WorkTime
1           1-2-2020 3:20:20       1-2-2020 3:25:20      00:05:00
1           2-2-2020 6:20:20       2-2-2020 7:20:20      01:00:00
3           1-3-2020 3:20:20       1-3-2020 3:29:20      00:09:00
```

Any ideas what to look for? Data-types? Table-definition? Table-relationships? We checked other Stackoverflow questions/answers, but no good ideas retrieved so far.

NOTE that a lot of join/merge features of Power BI are not available if direct-query is used and thus joining the tables is not really an option (we think).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on input provided by "mkRabbani" (see other answer) we investigated why "RELATED" does not function as expected. The problem originates in the access to the database. As suspected earlier the function delivers the expected results once the database access is switched to "import" instead of "direct-query".

As a workaround we now joins the data inside the SQL server by using traditional database views. Of course this only works for scenarios where the database is under control of the data analytics team.

Answer (score 1):

You need this following code for your new Calculated column.

Visit [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax) To know more about **RELATED**.

```
ResolutionAndWorkTime = Issues[ResolutionTime] + RELATED(SumWork[All work per item])
```

Comment: Hi R_R, thanks for your help. We now tried the RELATED function, but got the following error: "The column 'SumWork[All work per item]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.". Now we checked all relationships between the tables again, but they are as described above (we even modified them a bit, but no luck). What could this be related to?

Comment: Do you applied any FILTER in DAX or Visual level or Page level or Report level? Some filter might forcing to overwrite the relation between tables.

Comment: We try not to use regular filtering, atm we only use the slicer-visuals to narrow down results on a visual/page level. Would it make sense to remove all filters/slicers on our report for testing?

Comment: Yes, for testing purpose - please try removing all filters.

Comment: We tried with removing all filters and even now have setup a "clean" fresh new report, it still shows the same error from above (..doesnt have a relationship..). I sense this problem is related to the database/structure. Are there any constraints/mechanisms that have to be followed on the SQL server side for this to work?

Comment: At this stage, its difficult to suggest more :(